# launch mysqldump command to a remote server and save the backup file of mysqldump in the same remote server , in a specific folder

Tags: mysql, remote-server

I have a problem with mysqldump..

I know how to launch the mysqldump command from my pc to a remote server and automatically save the mysqldump file in my pc....

```
 mysqldump --user=... --password=... -h 192.xxx.xxx.xxx dbname > /Specific/folder/of/my pc/dbnamebackup.sql
```

but if i want to launch mysqldump command to a remote server (from my pc) and save the backup file of mysqldump in the same remote server, in a specific folder.

how can i do this?

i've tried:

```
mysqldump --user=... --password=... -h 192.xxx.xxx.xxx dbname > -h 192.xxx.xxx.xxx /folder/in/the/same/remote/server/
```

but:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "192.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

anyone can help me? :)

thanks in advance!!! :)

Comment: Connect to the remote host via ssh and execute mysqldump from there.

Comment: Is the remote server a Unix/Linux or Windows machine?

Comment: this command is launched by a script.. how can i connect with ssh and execute the mysqldump command in the remote server? Thanks @fancyPants

Comment: oh sorry @HartmutHolzgraefe the remote server is a windows machine (i use cygwin and works good) but i want do this on all machine linux or windows :)

Comment: @ale just give the command to execute after `ssh hostname`, like I didn in my answer below with `ssh 192.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat > /some/file'`

Comment: OK i'm trying! thank you for the support!

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe i try this: ssh user@192.xxx.xxx.xxx mysqldump --user=... --password=... dbname > dbname.sql
but this command save the file on my local machine... i use the wrong command? thanks in advance!

Comment: oh i'm sorry!! my stupid error! :) I had forgotten this: ' now everything works!! thank you very much for the support! best regards to @HartmutHolzgraefe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqldump` can only write to standard output, and output redirection can only write to local files or locally mounted network drives.

So you'd either need remote login to your server and run `mysqldump` there, or run it locally and then redirect output into a command that can transfer input to the remote server, e.g.:

```
mysqldump ... | ssh 192.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat > /some/remote/file'
```

Comment: No offense, but second approach is kind of retarded, isn't it? First you pull everything over network with mysqldump, then push it back over network with ssh.

Comment: Yes, it is if both servers are the same, it isn't if you have distinct database and backup machines ... still running mysqldump on the machine where the database is would make more sense though than having a total of three machines and two network hops involved